# Make code localized for Adelaide time Australia

Tags: javascript, date

I have a code that check if a business is open currently, however that seems to work only in UTC time and I cannot use the locale string to timezone as it's not supported where I am coding.

I can only choose between two options, to use UTC or EST time, and this affects everything in the code, the dates of holidays, the work hours, date, day..

The work hours for example are between 22:00 UTC to 6:30 UTC
however it is not working consistently.. I suspect the cause is how i set the daylight savings.. I just add another hour to the current time if it's within the DST time and not add if it isn't but I'm not sure if I can just do that with UTC..

** Cannot use any libraries

```
 var date = new Date();

 var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
 var utcHour = date.getUTCHours();
 var utcMinutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
 var theMonth = date.getMonth();
 var theDayOfMonth = date.getDate();
 var adelaideTime;
```

```
    if (isDayLightSaving() == true) {
        if ((utcHour + 1) != 24) { // time can't be 24:00 as it is not valid, manually change to 0 which means 12:00AM
            adelaideTime = utcHour + 1;
        } else adelaideTime = 0;
    } else {
        adelaideTime = utcHour;
    }
```

```
function isOfflineHourWeekDay() {
  try{
    debugLogs("isOfflineHourWeekDay");
    debugLogs("\n DayofWeek: " + dayOfWeek + " UTC Hour:" + utcHour + "\n adelaideTime:" + adelaideTime);
  }catch (err){debugLogs("IsWeekend Debug Error: " + err);}

    //check if it's working dayOfWeek
    if (dayOfWeek >= d_monday && dayOfWeek <= d_friday) {
        //check the work timings

        if ((adelaideTime <= 23) && (d_office_start_time <= 23) &&
            (adelaideTime > 16) && (d_office_start_time > 16) &&
            (adelaideTime != d_office_close_time)) { // if open hour is in previous day 
            //and current time is in previous day check
            //    23                  22
            if (adelaideTime < d_office_start_time) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            } // example: 23 < 22 gives false, you are in hours, 
            //21 < 22 gives true you are in off hours
        } else if ((adelaideTime != d_office_close_time)) { // if not between 16 and 23 and not exactly at closing time
            //      2                6    
            if (adelaideTime > d_office_close_time) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else { // if we are exactly at close time, check minutes
            if (utcMinutes > d_office_close_time_minutes) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    return false; // not a weekday
}
```

However it just doesn't seem to work correctly - and I feel like there has to be a more simple way to fight with UTC time to get it to work with Adelaide Australia time.

Comment: *I can only choose between two options, to use UTC or EST time* — why?  Your code runs in an ordinary web browser, right? What makes you think that you're limited to those two time zones?

Comment: try momenjs-timezones- https://momentjs.com/timezone/ or momentjs in general.

Comment: @HS I can't use Any libraries I'm afraid

Comment: @Pointy I will save the details but this is something running javascript inside java, forgot what's it called and so I can get the machine time it's on which is EST and UTC because it's built in to javascript

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You've described your problem, but short of writing it for you, what are you expecting from an answer? Personally I would run it entirely from UTC, and only convert it when it's being set/shown by the user.

Comment: @DBS well I am trying to understand if I am going incorrectly with this approach. Also I am not presenting the time to the user, I just need to tell to the user if the office is open or close (so true or false)

Comment: Maybe I can focus my question.. if i just have to change the daylight savings manually how can I get the days that are different between UTC and Adelaide be changed on the date object?

Comment: One strategy is to do everything in UTC, but treat the UTC values as if they were whatever timezone you want. That way you avoid any DST issues with the host system, but will have to apply DST rules yourself (noting that SA observed DST in 1917, 1942–1944 and 1971–present.). It really only works for modern dates (say after 1900) as before that offsets were nowhere near as standardised or simplified as currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a useful piece of code and matched it to my needs, just create your own 
DST function and it should be good enough!

```
//-------------------

   var date = new Date();

  // ET timezone offset in hours.
  if(isDayLightSaving === false){ 
    timezone = 9.5;
  } else timezone = 10.5;
// Timezone offset in minutes + the desired offset in minutes, converted to ms.
// This offset should be the same for ALL date calculations, so you should only need to calculate it once.
var offset = (date.getTimezoneOffset() + (timezone * 60)) * 60 * 1000;

// Use the timestamp and offset as necessary to calculate min/sec etc, i.e. for countdowns.
var timestamp = date.getTime() + offset,
    seconds = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000) % 60,
    minutes = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000 / 60) % 60,
    hours   = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000 / 60 / 60);

// Or update the timestamp to reflect the timezone offset.
date.setTime(date.getTime() + offset);
// Then Output dates and times using the normal methods.
var theDayOfMonth = date.getDate(),
    theHours = date.getHours(),
    dayOfWeek = date.getDay(),
    theMonth = date.getMonth(),
    theMinutes = date.getMinutes(),
    stringDate = date.toString();

//-------------------
```